# Laravel Eloquent Relationship by Models

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have a table called "categories" and there is a 3 table needed the id of categories
the 3 tables needed a categories id is "activies", "stories", "news" i really want to know how to fix this issue the stories and news table is running well im using php tinker to see if the relationship is running and the table activities it give me a null value, inside the activities table i`d input same category_id in the table of activities it gives always a null value given in php tinker

Models

```
Category.php
public function stories()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Story::class);
}
public function news()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Newy::class);
}
public function activites()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Activity::class);
}
Activity.php
public function category()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Category::class, 'category_id');
}
```

Comment: Because the name of your function contain (s) also laravel will search by exemple news_id that will return you null because laravel can’t get the column relation. This is a convention but I don’t know where we can see these convention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using `hasMany` in your `Category` Model, the opposite relationship in your `Activity` model should be `belongsTo()` and **not** `belongsToMany()`

```
public function category()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Category::class);
}
```

You can read more in the [documentation here](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#defining-relationships)